# Something weird happened when using i3bar with python scrpit

Tags: python, i3

Python newbie here.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import commands,time

def get_vol():
    vol =int(commands.getoutput("amixer get Master | grep -E -o '[0-9]
{1,3}?%' | head -1 | sed 's/.$//'"))
    full_block =(vol+10)/10-1 
    if vol%10==0:
        half_block =0
    else:
        half_block =1
    empty_block =10-(full_block+half_block)
    return '▮'*full_block+'▯'*half_block+'-'*empty_block

def NTime():
    return commands.getoutput("date '+%H:%M'")

def battery():
    prenBat =int(commands.getoutput('acpi battery | grep -o "[0-9]*[0-9]" | sed "1d"'))
    bat_icon =prenBat/20
    status =commands.getoutput('acpi battery | egrep -o -m1 "Discharging|Charging|AC|Full|Unknown"')
    if status== "Charging":
        return '❖'+' ●'*bat_icon+' ○'*(5-bat_icon)
    elif status=="Full":
        return '✔'+' ●'*bat_icon+' ○'*(5-bat_icon)
    else:
        return ' ●'*bat_icon+' ○'*(5-bat_icon)


battime =1
batNum =battery()

while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    volume =get_vol()
    nTime =NTime()
    while battime ==30:
        batNum =str(battery())
        battime =1
    else:
        battime =battime+1
    print batNum+" | "+volume+" | "+nTime
```

I was using this script direct to the i3bar(with out i3blocks),and it showed up nothing.And then I waited for a while.It showed up the barttery but no volume part and time part.Then, about 10 sec i guess.It showed up one or two blocks(▮) from the volume part.And nothing else.

I tryed to test it in terminal and it showed up nicely.
This is my i3bar part from i3config.

```
bar {
       position top 
       colors {
       statusline #414149
    background #8cb194
    separator #414149
    focused_workspace  #8cb194 #c8d087 #000000
    inactive_workspace #8cb194 #868974 #000000
    }
#   status_command i3blocks -c ~/.config/i3blocks.conf
    status_command ~/.config/bar.py
}
```

Sry for my English and newbie code.

Answer (score 0):

i3bar expected input format is json, as described at the following link from docs:

- [i3bar protocol](https://i3wm.org/docs/i3bar-protocol.html)

Some other remarks:

- as [commands](https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html) module is deprecated and not present in Python3, you might consider using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) instead for running commands.
- 0.1s of sleep time might be too agressive, you might consider changing the interval for a couple seconds as battery and volume values don't change this often, it would also avoid wasting too much CPU.
- Instead of using a lot of sed's, grep's you might consider doing string manipulation part using Python itself, resulting in more usable code even on different OS's.
- as described in PEP8 [other recommendations section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations), its good practice to ***"always surround operators with a single space on either side: assignment (=), augmented assignment (+=, -= etc.), comparisons (==, <, >, !=, <>, <=, >=, in, not in, is, is not), Booleans (and, or, not)."***
- putting the main body of code inside a main method allows you to import your code on other scripts or from the REPL -- aside form helping enforce scope and making your code look cleaner... good read on the [following link](https://realpython.com/python-main-function/).

Hope it helps!